# Extract Drupal database name from settings.php using shell script

Tags: bash, drupal, shell

As you know in Drupal there is a settings.php file with database connector.
$db_url = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename';
I would like a shell script to extract the string which is the 'databasename' and echo it.

Help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbname=`grep db_url settings.php | cut -d "/" -f 4`
echo ${dbname%"';"}
```

The first line searches settings.php for **db_url**, and then pipes that into cut that removes all text before the first 3 slashes. Finally the last **':** is removed from the end of the variable and it is echoed. This code is very dependant on the format of the url, it relies on the fact that there will always be 3 slashes before the database name.

Comment: Yes it also depends on the file format, the settings.php contains a lot of db_url strings so its printing everything

Comment: Oh really, I have never used Drupal and I presumed that $db_url was only declared once and then never used in that file. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for Drupal 7:

```
grep "      'database' =>" settings.php  | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "'" -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command line will extract the data base name from your Drupal 6 settings.php file (which is the one you are using, right?) and will echo it as output:

```
grep ^'$db_url' settings.php | cut -d "/" -f 4 | cut -d "'" -f 1
```

If you wish to use it in a bash script just create a text file, make it executable (chmod u+x filename) and run it:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep ^'$db_url' settings.php | cut -d "/" -f 4 | cut -d "'" -f 1
```

**Notice**: Drupal 7 settings.php file is slightly different and the suggested command/script **won't work** for it. Do you need it for Drupal 7 too?